# Python - SWIG in typemap does not work

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, swig

I was learning to wrap c++ codes into a Python module, and typemap is needed for functions like `int foo(int argc, char **argv);` For example, a simple c++ code can be

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Have " << argc << " arguments:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then I followed the SWIG tutorial [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn59) (34.9.2) to write the interface file for SWIG:

```
%module Args
%{
extern int foo(int argc, char **argv);
%}

%typemap(in) (int argc, char **argv) {
  /* Check if is a list */
  if (PyList_Check($input)) {
    int i;
    $1 = PyList_Size($input);
    $2 = (char **) malloc(($1+1)*sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < $1; i++) {
      PyObject *o = PyList_GetItem($input,i);
      if (PyString_Check(o))
    $2[i] = PyString_AsString(PyList_GetItem($input,i));
      else {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"list must contain strings");
    free($2);
    return NULL;
      }
    }
    $2[i] = 0;
  } else {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"not a list");
    return NULL;
  }
}

%typemap(freearg) (int argc, char **argv) {
  free((char *) $2);
}

extern int foo(int argc, char **argv);
```

However, after building the module, there is always an error in Python:

```
>>> import Args
>>> Args.foo(["foo","bar","spam","1"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list must contain strings
```

In the typemap it seems `$input` was indeed received as Python list, but something went wrong with `PyList_GetItem($input,i)`. Did I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Crystal ball at work: is this Python 3?

Comment: Yes. I used Python 3.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Bytes vs. characters

The fundamental issue is that Python 3 strings are **character** strings, while normal Python 2 strings and `char*` are **byte** strings.  (`char*` is usually also taken to be null-terminated.)  As such, `PyString_Check` has been removed in Python 3, and you have to deal with encoding in some fashion.

If you want to accept Python 3 `str` objects, use `PyUnicode` functions to check and encode the arguments.  Otherwise, pass `bytes` objects from Python: [bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for fixed ASCII strings (like `Args.foo([b"foo",b"bar",b"spam",b"1"])`), or else the result of [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode).

## Why the code compiles

The wrapper code generated by SWIG is compatible with [Python 2 or 3](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_python3support).
Even with `-py3`, it is written in Python 2 style supported by a number of compatibility macros (from `pyhead.swg`):

```
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000

/* ... */
#define PyString_Check(name) PyBytes_Check(name)
/* ... */

#endif
```

In the modern, mostly-3 world, it might be preferable for SWIG to use [`bytesobject.h`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/cporting.html#str-unicode-unification) instead.  It defines the synonym the other way, making the byte-string obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. Didn't realize the issue of Python 3. Changing `PyString` to `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` actually works!

Answer (score 0):

I found this question as a result of a google search where I received the same error

```
TypeError: list must contain strings
```

As the error only appeared after upgrading to Python 3, I was able to resolve it with the following change

```
Args.foo([b"foo",n"bar",b"spam",b"1"])
```

The `b` forced Python to send the strings as Python2 byte strings rather than the Python3 unicodes string in case this is helpful for anyone else.